# How to break jobs down into subtasks in projects (i.e. an Angular-Node.JS application)?

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, software-development, task-management

I am a new learner in web application field using Angular and Node.JS technologies. I watched some courses on Coursera for months and could create a Not-Bad web application for myself, but want I wish to do is to start a startup and create a new and big web application for my business. I exactly know what I want and maybe even I can speak about the technical details like what modules better to use and how design the database, etc.

But I don't know how to split the project into the daily oe even hourly tasks and give it to developers to do. I tried to see Agile- Scrum videos but couldn't get my answer there. Please help me to know how should I do it and give me links of tutorials about what I want to learn. Thanks you in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for you to break jobs down into multiple levels of subtasks if you use the [Hierarchical Task analysis](https://hfacmethods.wordpress.com/hierarchical-task-analysis/) method. **Hierarchical Task Analysis** is a detailed examination of the tasks users must do to achieve particular aims.

This document explains **how to carry out task analysis**: http://www.idemployee.id.tue.nl/g.w.m.rauterberg/lecturenotes/UFTtask-analysis.pdf

And this is a **comprehensive video** explaining the theory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRzi2dwoU4g

**Estimation of tasks** is explained in many posts, I recommend this one:
https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/28053/37983

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of all the features you want your application to have. For example, it might have a search function, a secure login, etc.

Prioritise the features, so that the most important items are at the top of the list.

> But I don't know how to split the project into the daily or even hourly tasks and give it to developers to do.

It is usually best if the developers doing the work also do the splitting up and creation of tasks.

Take the first, highest priority item on your list of features and show it to the developers. They can then discuss how best to implement it and decide on how it can be broken down into tasks. Repeat for the second item on the list and so on.

Once the developers have enough tasks to get started, they can begin work. When it looks like they are close to completing that work you can sit with them and break down some more features on your list so that they do not run out of tasks to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this specialization tha helped me to learn and understand more about how to break down projects to specific tasks: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/software-design-architecture